# Enable versioning on document libraries excluding some

Tags: document-library, powershell, versioning

I have enabled 10 major versions on all document libraries in my farm using the code below but I now need to exclude a few specific sites so that the major version number can be different to 10.

How would I go about adding that to this code?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$siteURL = $args[0]
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
  Write-Host "Inspecting " $web.Title
  foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
      Write-Host "Versioning enabled: " $list.EnableVersioning
      $host.UI.WriteLine()
      #Write-Host "MinorVersioning Enabled: " $list.EnableMinorVersions
      #$host.UI.WriteLine()
      #Write-Host "EnableModeration: " $list.EnableModeration
      #$host.UI.WriteLine()
      Write-Host "Major Versions: " $list.MajorVersionLimit
      $host.UI.WriteLine()
      #Write-Host "Minor Versions: " $list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit
      #$host.UI.WriteLine()
      $list.EnableVersioning = $true
      #Disable creation of minor (draft) versions (document libraries only)
      $list.EnableMinorVersions = $false
      $list.MajorVersionLimit = 10
      #$list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = 5
      $list.Update()
      Write-Host $list.Title " is updated with MajorVersionLimit 10 "
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asume you are filtering by site and not by library.

You could do something like this:

```
$ignoreSites = @("http://siteurl/site1", "http://siteurl/site2")

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$siteURL = $args[0]
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)
$webs = $site.AllWebs | ? {$_.Url -notin $ignoreSites}
foreach($web in $webs) {
 Write-Host "Inspecting " $web.Title
 foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
 if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
 Write-Host "Versioning enabled: " $list.EnableVersioning
 $host.UI.WriteLine()
    #Write-Host "MinorVersioning Enabled: " $list.EnableMinorVersions
    #$host.UI.WriteLine()
    #Write-Host "EnableModeration: " $list.EnableModeration
    #$host.UI.WriteLine()
 Write-Host "Major Versions: " $list.MajorVersionLimit
 $host.UI.WriteLine()
    #Write-Host "Minor Versions: " $list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit
    #$host.UI.WriteLine()
 $list.EnableVersioning = $true
    #Disable creation of minor (draft) versions (document libraries only)
 $list.EnableMinorVersions = $false
 $list.MajorVersionLimit = 10
    #$list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = 5
 $list.Update()
 Write-Host $list.Title " is updated with MajorVersionLimit 10 "
 }
 }
}
```

So you basically just filter the `$site.AllWebs` property.

It might be necessary to change `-notin` keyword to `-notcontains` (`-notin` seems to be available from PowerShell 3.0 on).