# Site Assets library still carries the 'No versioning' option

Tags: document-library, versioning

Am I correct in noticing that all default Site Assets libraries can still be set on 'No versioning' like it used to be for normal libraries?

Is there a way with powershell or similar to turn to 'no versioning' for selected libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible.

You can use `Set-PnPList` to change it to `No versioning`.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testSiteCollection"
Set-PnPList -Identity "Site Assets" -EnableVersioning:$false
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: This command will only turn the versioning off and not make the 'no versioning' option tick visible in the gui?

Comment: it will select the radio button for `no versioning`. You can check it by going to `List/library settings > Versioning settings`.

Comment: The radio button normally isnt there, so you mean that it will magically appear?

Comment: That's strange, i checked in my SPO first release tenant's Site Assets library. It is indeed there, [check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvrRq.png)

Comment: in your code, Identity is the name of library? by chance is there another code to free up the minimum number of versions (lets say from 100 to 10)?

Comment: yes, its the name of the library. You can use it as `Set-PnPList -Identity "Demo Library" -EnableVersioning $true -EnableMinorVersions $true -MajorVersions 20 -MinorVersions 10`

Answer (score 1):

My "Site Assets" libraries, both on-prem and O365 have major versions enabled by default.

> Create major versions

There are a couple of properties that you can tweak to configure versioning:

EnableVersioning

EnableMinorVersions

MajorVersionLimit

MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit

[List members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee545367%28v%3Doffice.15%29)

If you're looking for disabling versioning, the line you are looking for is:

```
$list.EnableVersioning = $false
```

More here:

[Enable versioning on document libraries excluding some](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154516/enable-versioning-on-document-libraries-excluding-some)

Comment: I have looked in a site assets library of a sharepoint tenancy born in 2018 and I could turn off versioning for it (which makes sense, you do not need versioning in the site assets). If it is an improvement by microsoft I am happy