# Alternatives to Versioning?

Tags: versioning, version-history

Are there alternatives to use Versioning?  I have a customer who works in an environment that is strict on using versioning AND, for this particular project, rightfully so (about 2000 pdf files in one library).

So can a simple fix be two folders, one that states Final and another called Draft (with maybe a few versions of the doc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read this question/answer you find a powershell script to have back the 'No versioning' option in libraries

[Site Assets library still carries the 'No versioning' option](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258673/site-assets-library-still-carries-the-no-versioning-option)

The final and draft status can be turned into a choice column that you switch at your need.

However the concept of versioning is not the mere declaration that something is draft or final but the ability to retrieve previous versions of the file.

Comment: I would add to turn on the approval workflow settings to ensure the final version of a document. Even though, you can create a Microsoft Flow workflow to move or copy final documents to a "public" library to be available for everybody.

Comment: @susan, thank you for your explanation and clarification of the concept of versioning.  I'll also use the final/draft status as a column.  I'll mark this as an answer.